# mysql.connector+mysql hangs on fetching

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x

I have a database that is accessed from python3 script using `mysql.connector`. Mysql version is `5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`, tested on Linux Mint 17 x64 and a few other Linux machines. The script requests a chunk of data (from tens to about five thousand records) and then sends about ten times as many single-row requests. After that, the connection is closed and a new one opens to do the same. Alternatively, several connections are run in parallel. The entire script is available [at github](https://github.com/SynedraAcus/phylome/blob/master/process_outers.py)

It works fine for ~5 to ~50 times (per process, if launched in multiprocessing pool), then hangs. The `python3` process is sleeping, `mysql` shows a single sleeping connection per process. If the script is killed, the traceback is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morozov/tools/phylome/process_outers.py", line 116, in <module>
    r = wrapper(fasta)
  File "/home/morozov/tools/phylome/process_outers.py", line 108, in wrapper
    password=args.p, database=args.d)
  File "/home/morozov/tools/phylome/process_outers.py", line 43, in process_fasta
    result = cursor.fetchall()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 825, in fetchall
    (rows, eof) = self._connection.get_rows()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 671, in get_rows
    rows = self._protocol.read_text_result(self._socket, count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 309, in read_text_result
    packet = sock.recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 245, in recv_plain
    read = self.sock.recv_into(packet_view, rest)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

After restarting the script, the file it hang on is processed alright and it hangs on some other one down the line. What should I fix to keep it running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not the slightest idea what was wrong, but using [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) instead of [mysql.connector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python) fixed it.